Testing forecasting accuracy - outliers [ with example]
I have a simple model that produces forecast values. The model works on hourly data. Now, I am only interested in observations with flags. I would like to identify where the forecasts are significantly different from the actual values.
I am considering the following two metrics — which one would work better? (See Option 1 and Option 2 below in the code)
Or should I focus on RMSE, MAE, etc.?
# Sample Data: Actual and Forecasted values
actual <- c(100, 110, 95, 120, 105, 130, 125)
forecasted <- c(102, 108, 97, 150, 103, 128, 123)

plot(actual, type = "o", col = "blue", pch = 16, lwd = 2,
     ylim = range(c(actual, forecasted)), ylab = "Values",
     xlab = "Index", main = "Actual vs Forecasted Values")
lines(forecasted, type = "o", col = "red", pch = 16, lwd = 2)

# Calculate Residuals (Difference between actual and forecasted values)
residuals <- actual - forecasted

# Define a threshold:
# Option 1: (e.g., 2 standard deviations)
dynamic_threshold <- 2 * sd(residuals)
dynamic_outliers <- abs(residuals) > dynamic_threshold

# Option 2: (e.g., 2 standard deviations based on mean and sd from actual data)
upper_threshold  <- mean(actual)+2 * sd(actual)
lower_threshold  <- mean(actual)-2 * sd(actual)

outliers_forecasted <- (forecasted > upper_threshold) | (forecasted < lower_threshold)


Your first option is better.  Or you could just plot one against the other or plot the residuals to see that the forecasted values are each $\pm2$ from the corresponding actual values, except for the $(120,150)$ pair.

You should definitely use residuals, not the actual data, because the data could show patterns such as trend, seasonality, or other types of non-stationarity. The residuals will be what's left after removing the signal.
However, if you have serious outliers, then the fitted model could be affected by them, and that will potentially cause the outliers to be hidden. Use robust methods to estimate the model if possible.
Also, because there are potential outliers in the residual series, you shouldn't use the standard deviation as a measure of scale because it will be affected by the outliers. Something robust, such as the MAD, would be better. For a normal distribution, the MAD is equal to 0.6745 times the standard deviation. So if you wanted an equivalent to a 2 sigma rule, use $2/0.6745 \approx 3$ MAD. But that would give you about 4.6% false positives. A higher threshold might be better. The equivalent of a 3 sigma rule would be $3/0.6745 \approx 4.4$ MAD which would give you about 0.3% false positives.

I agree with Rob Hyndman that you should definitely use residuals, not actuals. After all, you are interested in "where the forecasts are significantly different from the actual values" (emphasis mine): and this means you want to look at residuals.
(That said, "residuals" typically refers to the difference between actuals and in-sample fits. "Errors" is a more common terminology for the difference between actuals and forecasts.)
That said, what you are implicitly doing by adding and subtracting a multiple of some standard deviation is calculating prediction intervals and checking whether your actuals are outside those PIs. This is precisely the correct approach.
However, I would very much recommend that you use a theory-driven approach to calculating those PIs. Right now, you are using the SDs of the actuals to calculate the PIs. But of course if your actuals contain a lot of signal (you mention that you have hourly data; such data often has multiple-seasonalities, which can indeed be modeled and forecasted, see here), then the SD of the actuals may very much overstate the uncertainty in future errors once you have captured and forecasted the signal.
In addition, treating PIs rigorously may allow you to handle (conditional) heteroskedasticity: variance is very often not constant, and may, e.g., be higher during the day than during the night for your hourly data. If you don't model this, then you will get unnecessarily many false positives during the day, and false negatives during the night, since your threshold should be higher during daytime than during nighttime (but if you use just a single SD, you won't be doing this). Unfortunately, many common forecasting methods don't handle this very well, but you might want to look at GAMLSS models on well-crafted predictors. (Since you are only interested in specific "flagged" data points, these flags might inspire you to create more features for such causal models, something that standard forecasting methods may have a hard time with.)
And even if you do want to keep things simple right now, keeping points like these in the back of your head will be useful if you want to extend your forecasting model later on.
So: better to use established forecasting methods that give you PIs, then compare the actuals to those PIs. You may find this helpful: Resources/books for project on forecasting models.

Take a look at Grubbs test for outliers. It's similar to your approach, but takes into account the tail analysis. You would apply it to residuals.
I have a problem with this approach though. I don't believe that outliers should be detected based solely on statistical tests. Outliers are observations that do not belong to the data set, e.g. the data entry error led to extra 0 in the measurement or there was an equipment failure that produced the incorrect reading etc. This in contrast to stock index return observation March 16 (COVID) - this wasn't an error, you can't simply toss this out despite extreme deviation from norm.
